# How to create .exe from QT Design Studio project?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, qt-design-studio

I want to create an animation on QT Design Studio application and generate an executable file that will play it. I can export the project with cmake build files or as a deployable project.

Where should I go from here?

I tried opening the CMakeLists.txt with QT Creator, and at some point I was able to open a project, but the .exe file failed to open on it's own. I am no longer able to use the same method to open other projects however because of missing files every time.

https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/quick-converting-ui-projects.html
Following this, QT does not give me the option to build with qmake

Comment: If the application doesn't run, does it give any error messages? It sounds like you're missing a few essential libraries that you'll have to deploy along with the executable. The alternative is to build a static application, but that's not easy.

Comment: If I create a default 3D project off of QT design, then generate it as an executable package and open the qmlproject file with QT creator, I receive the errors: "Type Screen01 unavailable", "Type Constants unavailable", and "module "QtQuick.Studio.Application" is not installed qml: Did not load any objects, exiting.". I've played around with files in earlier scratch projects and didn't get far, but what should I do at this point?